# Session is not getting maintained, getting redirected to the login page again

Tags: java, apache, unix, webserver

I have my web server configuration on apache ,while I login to the application and redirected to the desired page.When I copy and paste the URL back again on the same browser, I am being redirected to the login page .Hence instead of maintaing the session < I have to login again.Can you please let me know if there are any changes to be made in my web server configuration?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The log-in is handled by the apache webserver with basic authentication or something like that ?

Comment: Hi All,The issue has been resolved.I made a silly mistake.Didnt deployed the application on the app server

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.